# How to delete all selected rows at once in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to wirte a function to delete all selected Ids at once.

I have a delete funtion for delete one ID `onDeleteHandler(id: number)`

```
  onDeleteHandler(id: number) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      return;
    }
     this.service.delete(id).toPromise(); // this works perfectly
  }
```

Now I want use this function to delete all Ids function.

```
  deleteMultiSelected() {

    const idArr = this.selectedItems.map(i => i.id);  // this is something like [id1, id2, id3]

    // NEED A CODE FOR DELETE ALL AT ONCE using onDeleteHandler(id: number) method

  }
```

How can i do this?

I must use this `onDeleteHandler(id: number)` this method to delete all selected IDs

Comment: How about `onDeleteHandler(...ids: number[]) {}`? Call it with `onDeleteHandler(...idArr)`

Comment: @Pieterjan to use this `onDeleteHandler(...ids: number[]) {}`  we need to call anther API. I need to write another backend function. I don't want this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to make multiple calls simultaneously. So, map your array of items, to an array of observables, then forkJoin like this:

```js
deleteMultiSelected() {
  const deletes = this.selectedItems.map(item => this.service.delete(item.id));
  
  forkJoin(deletes).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this a is a valid solution. The other one is to create a bulk delete that accepts an array of ids.